# looping custom post type as checkboxes in wp alchemy

Tags: wordpress

I'm running in a bit of trouble with Wordpress. I'm using wpalchemy the add custom meta fields to my post types. I have a post type of employees and a post type customers. I want on the customers meta box a list of all the employees with checkboxes so the admin can show what employee works with each client. The code I have so far is this:

```
<?php

        $type = 'medewerkers';
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => $type,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'caller_get_posts'=> 1
        );

        $my_query = null;
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

            $metabox->the_group_open();
            while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                <?php

                    $meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID());
                    $naam = $meta['voornaam'][0].' '.$meta['achternaam'][0];

                ?>
                    <br/><?php $metabox->the_field($naam); ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $meta['pasfoto'][0]; ?>" height="40" width="40" style="vertical-align: middle">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="<?php $metabox->the_name(); ?>" value="1"<?php if ($metabox->get_the_value()) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?>/> <?php echo $naam; ?>

                <?php

                endwhile;
            $metabox->the_group_close();
        }
    ?>
```

It works, however I'm not satisfied. The employees are stored as separate items instead of an array. I want to be able to loop, for example, trough an array in the front end to show all the employees associated with the current client on display.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've manage to fix it:

```
<?php

        $type = 'medewerkers';
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => $type,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'caller_get_posts'=> 1
        );

        $my_query = null;
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

            while($mb->have_fields_and_multi('medewerkers')):
            $mb->the_group_open();
            while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                <?php

                    $meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID());
                    $naam = $meta['voornaam'][0].' '.$meta['achternaam'][0];

        ?>
                    <?php $metabox->the_field($naam); ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $meta['pasfoto'][0]; ?>" height="40" width="40" style="vertical-align: middle">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="<?php $metabox->the_name(); ?>" value="1"<?php if ($metabox->get_the_value()) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?>/> <?php echo $naam; ?>
        <?php
            endwhile;
            $mb->the_group_close();
            endwhile;
        }

    ?>
```